# Replacing special character with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, formatting, special-characters

i need to replace the special character "[" and "]" in this syntaxe:

var Data = "[{\tst??}]";

It's a json format and i need to show all the information individually so i need a tip in jquery to replace or delete the "[" and "]" they causing me troubles when i whant to show the information.

Thank you.

Comment: Why jQuery? It isn't as if it is a library focused on either string or JSON manipulation.

Comment: Removing the `[` and `]` characters will make it invalid JSON so you won't be able to parse it at all. That doesn't sound like it will help.

Comment: try to use JSON.parse to convert it to object

Comment: When I try to parse that String as JSON, I get an Error. The object, and the Array at `BeneficiaryList` are missing their closing brackets.

Comment: the result displayed it's via JSON.parse(data)

Comment: Do you want to remove only the first [ and the last ] or others [..] in your string?

Comment: @Thomas i've edited the object you can try now !

Comment: @CiroRa the first and the last ! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `slice` to remove the first and the last char (i.e, [ and ])

```
CleanData=Data.slice(1, -1);
```

Use this to remove all [ followed by { in order to get only { and the same is for }] that are replaced with }. In this way, something like [] is not replaced

```
var res = Data.replace("[{","{"); 
var CleanData=res.replace("}]","]");
```

Comment: thank you CiroRa , but if there is a method to remove all the "[" and "]" from all the content, i'll be greatfull !

Comment: added new solution

Comment: where? I've tried and it works. Can you give me more details?

Answer (score 1):

```
var Data = "...."; // here is your data
var obj = JSON.parse(Data);
```

after this, `obj` will contain:

```
[ { AccountNumber: '664009500',
    AccountNumberLong: '230100950070',
    Autorizations: [],
    AvailableBalance: 0,
    Balance: 2243.93,
    BeneficiaryList: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    CanCreditAccount: true,
    CanDebitAccount: true,
    CodeOffre: 'CPTCHQ11',
    Currency: 'MAD',
    EligibleServiceList: [ '300014', '300018', '300013', '300016' ],
    Entitled: 'MONSIEUR HOUSSAM MOUBTAHIL',
    IsDemat: 'true',
    LstClientidTuteur: null,
    OpeningDate: '/Date(1408662000000+0000)/',
    OperationDate: '/Date(-62135596800000+0000)/',
    OperationLastDate: '/Date(1465776000000+0000)/',
    OperationOAA: null,
    OperationOSD: null,
    Operations: null,
    RelationType: null,
    SitexAccountList: [],
    SitexTierList: null,
    TotalBalance: 0,
    TotalCredit: 32151.26,
    TotalDebit: 29255.77,
    legalSituation: 'MJ' } ]
```

nothing to change :)

you have a list of objects, if your list will have only one element - take `obj[0]`, if more - just loop through them (using, `for` loop or jQuery's `.each`)..

Answer (score -1):

try to use : `Data.toString().trim().replace("[", anotherCharacter)`

Comment: how can i replace the both '[' and ']' in this syntaxe with "space" ?